# Check the checkbox by default

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

My code :

```
<label ng-class="[getClasscolor(0)]"><input class="opened" ng-checked="getStatut(data.statut_cas_id_statut1, 0)" ng-model="data.statut_cas_id_statut1" value="0" type="checkbox">&nbsp;Open&nbsp;</label>
```

I would check this checkbox by default and call the function getStatut by default.
How can I do that ? I'm starting with angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
<div ng-app="">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true">
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQDts/337/)**

You can try to use `ng-change="!key || getStatut(data.statut_cas_id_statut1, 0)"`

So it would be like

```
<div ng-app="">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" 
     ng-change="!key || getStatut(data.statut_cas_id_statut1, 0)">
</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain the "key" ?